# Docker Cannot link to a non running container

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I need to create Rails and Mysql containers with docker-compose. When I try to create links between containers with `docker-compose up`, I get

> Cannot start container
>   9b271c58cf6aecaf017dadaf5b Cannot link to a non running container:
>   /puma_db_1 AS /puma_web_1/db

Files

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install git curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev

RUN apt-get -y install libmysqlclient-dev
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /root/.rbenv
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> $HOME/.profile
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> $HOME/.bashrc

RUN rbenv install 2.1.5
RUN rbenv global 2.1.5
RUN gem install rails -v 4.0.11

ADD app.tar.gz /home/
WORKDIR /home/app

RUN bundle install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
db:  
  image: mysql:latest
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: app_development
    MYSQL_USER: mysql
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: onetwo
    ROOT_PASSWORD: onetwo
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  ports:
    - "4000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

Comment: most likely the `db` container fails to start. What does `docker-compose up db` do? is the mysql service fine in that case? Also provide in your question the `docker-compose up` output

Comment: @Thomasleveil thanks!! with  `docker-compose up db` i get  `error: database is uninitialized and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD not set`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Most likely the `db` container fails to start.

Make sure it works fine by starting only the `db` service. You can do that with the following command:

```
docker-compose up db
```

If it appears the MySQL service is not running after this command, then you found the origin of your problem.

Comment: This is pointing in the right direction. Typically you'd see this if a linked container fails to start. Interestingly, the error message doesn't tell me that.

Answer (score 44):

Not specifically related to MySQL but more the message `ERROR: for <service>  Cannot link to a non running container: /b2f21b869ccc_<dependency>_1 AS /<service>_1/<dependency>_1`

I found that the dependency container had a different id than the one given (`b2f21b869ccc` in my example above)

Solved simply by running

  `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate <service>`

which caused it to recreate the dependency and fix the link to the correct docker id

Comment: I ended up doing `docker-compose rm` which also removes all the containers. I guess running `docker rm CONTAINER_ID` replacing the offending container id in there should also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was a life saver.

Answer (score 35):

For me, it did not help running docker-compose up db.

This did the trick for me:

`sudo service docker restart`

and then continuing with docker-compose up (-d)

Comment: This worked for me too, probably because I had just installed docker-engine and had not restarted the server. Even though docker-engine seemed to be working, restarting it apparently fixed some problem.

Answer (score 5):

You might try out the new features of docker networking, To do this, You must remove the *link* parameter in your *docker-compose.yml* , and initialize the container with the [`--x-networking option`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

```
docker-compose --x-networking up -d
```

To prevent docker generate random names for the containers, which are added to the */etc/hosts* file of the respective network for every container, you can use the [`container_name:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container-name) key in the *docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
db:  
  container_name: db
  image: mysql:latest
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: app_development
    MYSQL_USER: mysql
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: onetwo
    ROOT_PASSWORD: onetwo
web:
  container_name: web
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  ports:
    - "4000:3000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue:

- I have gotten this error whenever `docker-compose` successfully
  builds a set of `Images`, but one of those `Images`fails to
  run (e.g. launch into its own `Container`).
- In this case, I suspect the `Image`, underlying your
  `puma_db_1` `Container`, is failing to `run`. You can
  find the name of this `Image` by running `docker ps -a`. That said, its name is most likely `puma_db`

Solution:

- To get at the cause, you can try `docker-compose up
  <service_name>` or `docker-compose up db`
- Alternatively, I find the error message by running `docker run
  <image_name>` more useful. In this case, that would be `docker
  run puma_db`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for `mssql.link`, as I am not using local database (rather using the one we have on staging), all I had to do is just comment that line out by editing Dockerfile script:

```
# DOCKER_ARGS="${DOCKER_ARGS} --link mssql-server-linux:mssql.link"
```

This solution may help someone or may be no one, but it sorted it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you started the container `lets say X` with a link `--link keen_visvesvaraya` and then once `X` is up the linked container was stopped, but `X` kept running . Now if you try to `docker exec` into `X` you get this error.

Yah solution is to restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with elasticsearch - symfony - and docker

```
Can not link to a non-running container:/43c1d3b410db_myindex_elasticsearch_1 AS /myindex_apache_1/elasticsearch
```

the solution is to delete the content of the data volume

`elasticsearch:
     image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2
     Volumes:
        - ./docker/volume/elasticsearch: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data`
and run `docker-composer up -d` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command Because It's working for me

```
docker run --name standlone-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when restart the service.

```
Cannot link to a non running container: /c7e8ba2cc034_<service1>_1 AS /<service2>/<srvice1>
```

In my case there is Exited service2, so remove the container (`docker rm`) and start the service 2.

Answer (score -1):

you need to modify the db: in yml file to include "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD" in environment section

```
db:
  environment:
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

Comment: Are you sure that this answer is relevant to this old question? As I see that all the other answers are about missing network-connectivity and yours is about configuring Postgres.